# Integral of the limit of a increasing sequence of real functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges pointwise fo $f$ (not necessarily continuous), with $f_{n+1}(x) \geq f_{n}(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)dx$ exists.

Prove or disprove: $f$ is integrable, and $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)dx$

I didn't find any counterexamples so I'm trying to prove it. Because that $f$ may not be continuous, so we can't use Dini's theorem and $\{f_n\}$ may not converge uniformly. I think when $n\rightarrow\infty$ the limit of the measure of $\{x|f(x)-f_n(x)>\delta\}$ should be zero for a fixed $\delta$. (and then the prove will be similar with the case of having uniform convergence), but I can't prove it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried Darboux integral, but I didn't get anything useful

Comment: Please include your try by editing the original post.

Comment: @AnneBauval thx it's a typo, just fixed it

Comment: What kind of integrability are you considering? The claim is trivial if we consider Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: If you are considering Riemann integrability, consider $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n,&x\leq 1/n^2 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, & x > 1/n^2 \end{cases} $$